# Does PHP hash() support WHIRLPOOL by default?

Tags: php, hash, cryptography

Does PHP's hash function supported WHIRLPOOL by default? I believe it does but I wanted to ask to be sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `hash()` in PHP should support Whirlpool by default. Try calling:

```
print_r(hash_algos());
```

to see the list of supported hashing methods.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  And your code might look something like this:

```
$myHash = hash( 'whirlpool', $salt . $password );
```

More details can be found in this excellent article:  [PHP Password Security](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/php-password-security)